# How does Celery worker run the code defined elsewhere in a task?

Tags: python, django, celery, message-queue, django-celery

I tried reading official documentation as well as other SO threads, but it is still not clear how Celery works.

From what I understand:

1. **Django app**: Celery is installed in Django (or any app) where `@shared_task` decorator function defines the work to be performed.
2. **Message broker**: A message broker gets this task from 1. and queues it.
3. **Celery Worker**: A completely separate Celery worker picks up the task and runs it. This worker can be in a completely different machine even, so long as it has access to the message broker.

So, then the burning question is:

**How does the Celery worker get the code defined in @shared_task to run the task?**

Basically, how does 3. get what's defined in 1. if they are only connected using a message broker? Is the python code stored in the message broker as string? What is the data structure of the message broker item/record?

Answer (score 7):

After spending some time and actually implementing Celery, I was able to figure out what's actually going on. This is perhaps a short coming of my own ways of learning or the documentation overlooks it, either way, I want to leave it here in case others are also wondering the same.

The following is completely not obvious IMO:

1. **Django app**: Celery tasks are defined here. It has Celery installed as dependency.
2. **Message broker**: A message broker gets this task from 1. and queues it.
3. **Celery Worker**: This is actually not a separate python app that only contains Celery. It is a *full blown instance of 1.*. So you launch Django *twice*, one is producing tasks and the other is working on them. Both containing the same `@shared_task` function.

Caveats that the documentation should explain:

- If you update your main Django app and not restart Celery worker, your workers are working on a stale version of the `@shared_task` function.
- The app in 1. is launched using Gunicorn (or whatever you want), but App in 3. is launched using `celery -A "your_app" workers -l INFO`. It's not running Gunicorn, but still contains all the code in 1.

I think right off the bat in the introduction of Celery, they should explain that both the producer and worker instances contain your source code.

Comment: Thank you @Neil. I was wondering the exact same thing. I came to the same conclusion as you but wasn’t sure if I was right. This has given me some confidence in it.